# What are the sets in the partition of the integers arising from congruence modulo 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

i.e. Give a description of each of the congruence classes modulo 3.

I think I understand this but I wanted to verify. In my notes I've read "If $R$ is the congruence modulo $m$ relation on the set $\mathbb Z$ of integers then $\mathbb Z/m = \{[0], [1],...[m-1]\}$".

So for $3$ we have the classes $[0],[1],$ and $[2]$. I then described each as follows:

$$[0] = \{0 + 3k\} = \{0,3,6,9,..\}$$

$$[1] = \{1+3k\} = \{1,4,7,10,...\}$$

$$[2] = \{2+3k\} = \{2,5,8,11,...\}$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Where do the negative integers fall?

Comment: No, you are not correct. Where are the negative numbers? $\Bbb Z$ denotes the set of *all* integers. Then $\Bbb Z/m$ still consists of equivalence classes containing positive and negative numbers.

Comment: That is fine for writing the sets of *non-negative* integers.  If you were to write $\{1,4,7,10,\dots\}$ however, most people would assume that you are implying that these numbers are all positive.  To emphasize the fact that you include negative numbers as well, it is better to write it as a two-sided list like $\{\dots,-5,-2,1,4,7,\dots\}$ or to write this in set-builder notation as $\{1+3k~:~k\in\Bbb Z\}$ and leave it at that

Comment: So does the rule Z/m = [0], [1], [m-1] work the other direction such that the equivalence classes are [-2],[-1],[0],[1],[2]?

Comment: $\dots=[-1]=[m-1]=[2m-1]=\dots = \{\dots,-m-1,-1,m-1,2m-1,\dots\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't really understand that. So what are the equivalence classes for mod 3 that accounts for the negative integers?

Comment: You could have written them as $[0],[1],[2]$ as most people do.  Or you could have written them as $[10002],[4],[-43]$ if you were so inclined, or you could have written them in many other different ways.  The point that we're trying to get across is that when you wrote that $[0]$ was "*The set $\{0,3,6,9,\dots\}$*" that will be interpreted by most people incorrectly if not wrong in your own mind as well and should have instead been written $\{\dots,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,\dots\}$ so that it is clear that the sequence continues in both directions rather than only in the one direction.

Comment: You do not need to write the same equivalence class more than once... so you do not need to write $[-2],[-1],[0],[1],[2]$ since the equivalence class $[-1]$ *is identical to the equivalence class* $[2]$.  Notice:  $[-1]=\{\dots,-4,-1,2,5,\dots\}$ while $[2]=\{\dots,-1,2,5,8,\dots\}$ both describe the same set.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok I think I understand. [0],[1],[2] is correct but I need to expand it to incorporate the negative numbers. So I should represent 0 as [0] = {0 - 3k}? That way when k is negative it'll get the positive numbers and when k is positive itll get the negative numbers?

Comment: $\{0-3k~:~k\in\Bbb Z\}$ is the same set as $\{0+3k~:~k\in\Bbb Z\}$ and is the same set as $[0]$ and is the same set as $\{\dots,-6,-3,0,3,6,\dots\}$ and is the same set as $\{0,3,-3,6,-6,9,-9,12,-12,\dots\}$.  It doesn't matter how you decide to write it from one of these options.  What we were complaining about however was you writing it as $\{0,3,6,9,12,\dots\}$ which is how people choose to notate $\{0+3k~:~k\in\Bbb N\}$ which is different than $\{0+3k~:~k\in\Bbb Z\}$ since it doesn't contain any negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The comments suggest that the main terminology you need is congruence modulo $n$.
So we have
$$
a\equiv b\bmod 3 \Longleftrightarrow 3\mid a-b
$$
in the ring $\Bbb Z$. This has nothing to do with negative or positive numbers. It concerns all integers, i.e,
$$
-1\equiv 2\equiv 5 \bmod 3
$$
for example. In the quotient ring $R=\Bbb Z/3$ these become equalities:
$$
-7=-4=-1=2=5=8
$$
in $R$, and so on. So in the quotient all these numbers are just treated as one element, namely as $[2]$ in your terminology.

**Application**: The equation $x^2+y^2=7919$ has no integer solution.

*Proof*: Assume it has an integer solution. Then it also has one in the quotient $R=\Bbb Z/4$. Here we obtain $x^2+y^2=3$, which clearly has no solution there. Contradiction.